# Select Query Ignore Field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named test with below values. I want to fetch how many users are using open id.

```
----+----------+-----------+
| NAME   | PROVIDER | OPERATION |
+--------+----------+-----------+
| Samuel | Google   | P         |
| Samuel | Google   | V         |
| Kannan | Google   | V         |
| George | Google   | V         |
| Bush   | Google   | V         |
| Bush   | Yahoo    | V         |
+--------+----------+-----------+
```

Query: `select distinct(Name) from test group by PROVIDER`

Result:

```
+-----------------------+----------+  
| count(distinct(NAME)) | PROVIDER |  
+-----------------------+----------+  
|                     4 | Google   |  
|                     1 | Yahoo    |  
+-----------------------+----------+
```

In this query I want to ignore the count which a user operation is **P** for a PROVIDER . How can I do this in a single query?

Output should be

```
+-----------------------+----------+
| count(distinct(NAME)) | PROVIDER |
+-----------------------+----------+
|                     3 | Google   |
|                     1 | Yahoo    |
+-----------------------+----------+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this,

```
SELECT  `Provider`, COUNT(DISTINCT Name)
FROM    tableName
WHERE   NAME NOT IN
            (
                SELECT Name
                FROM tableName
                WHERE Operation = 'P'
            )
GROUP BY Provider
```

## [*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/51b33/2)

Comment: you are welcome @RBK ! just don't forget to accept answer if you feel it really solved your problem :)

Comment: @RBK i think that's the best solution i can suggest :)

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(distinct(Name)) from test where operation != 'P' group by PROVIDER;
```

Comment: It does n't work . I want to subtract the count who's OPERATION is P .

Comment: @John Woo , Is this query is optimized I can run this query which the table contain millions of rows . Please comment your suggestion.

Comment: @RBK i think that's the best i can suggest :)